# Reading a '.txt' data file in columns to a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a file like

```
86999490    88641807@N00    newyork truck city night light red road street springstreet
86999495    34675390@N00    sky
86999496    97245056@N00    scarborough
86999503    97245056@N00    york
86999507    63656023@N00    grifan
86999508    63656023@N00    grifan
86999509    63656023@N00    grifan
```

and I want to read it to a matrix that keeps each column separate.

How could I do it?

Comment: Using textscan: http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/textscanDemo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use textscan with a tab (\t) as delimeter:

```
fid = fopen(fileNm, 'r');
while~feof(fid)
    output = textscan(fid, '%d %s %s', 'Delimiter', '\t')
end
```

Comment: There's really no need for the while loop here.